# In the python datetime why is the first month, 'January', = 1, but 'Monday', the first day of the week = 0?

Tags: python

I was just learning about the datetime module, and noticed that when you use `.month` it provides the month in a range of 1 to 12, where 1 is January. When using `.weekday`, however, it provides the weekday in a range of 0 to 6.

Most list indexes start at 0, so why wouldn't January, from the list of months also be 0, not 1? I looked at the python datetime docs, but didn't see an explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: because that's the design decision they made ... 0 as a month feels unnatural ... zero as a day of the week feels less so

Comment: I see days as 1-7 in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In different parts of the world different calendars are followed : Gregorian Calendar, Julian Calendar, Vedic Calendar and so on.

**1)** Months are generally numbered from 1 to 12(I have not seen anyone associating January with 0. There could be exceptions which I am not aware of). That leads me to focus on the second point - i:e numbering of weekdays.

**2)** Weekdays are numbered differently in different parts of the world. Some associate Monday with 0 and some with 1. For that matter, Date formats are represented differently in North America, Europe and in other places or in different types of calendars. This causes confusion.

To address the problem mentioned in #2 the *International Organization for Standardization* (ISO) came up with a date format to express a numeric calendar date in standardised way to eliminate ambiguity. Part of the world considers Monday to be associated with number 0 and others with 1.
As per Gregorian calendar wikipedia page(please check the hyperlink mentioned below): *"Opinions vary about the numbering of the days of the week. **ISO 8601**, in common use worldwide, starts with Monday=1"*

Now speaking of **python**: I have not read/ known what did make the writer of **weekday()** method to have return 0 for Monday and 6 for Sunday. But then the other option is there which is more standardised. i:e

**isoweekday(): Returns integer 1 for Monday and 7 for Sunday.** This follows the ISO format - hence such numbering.

So I assume, the author created a method for everyone and that makes the usage more flexible and more specific at the same time.

Below snippet of code shows both the methods:

```
import datetime as dt
td = dt.datetime(2020,2,17) # checking for 17 Feb 2020
print ("This is weekday() method -->",td.weekday(),"--->", dt.datetime.strftime(td,'%a'))
print ("This is isoweekday() method -->",td.isoweekday(),"--->", dt.datetime.strftime(td,'%a'))
```

Output:

```
This is weekday() method --> 0 ---> Mon
This is isoweekday() method --> 1 ---> Mon
```

for further reading on calendar algorithms / types you may check these links:
[ISO_week_date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), [Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week), [Gregorian_calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), [isoweekday](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that this method provides Monday as '1' as an alternative. This makes it easier to understand in my mind. I was hoping to understand more of the 'why' behind the decision to make Monday 0, though. Maybe it'll help if you can also clarify thy is the isoweekday method provides it as 1 as a comparison?

Comment: @EdwardHutchins, I have edited my answer - hope it answers your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 3):

When you write out the date you will write it out with the month, day, and year. Today is 2/15/20 (I am not sure how it work in places other than America.) This establishes a standard that the number 2 corresponds to Febuary. There is no standard setting days of the week to any number so it treats them as 7 items and starts counting at 0 as normal

Comment: Thank you for your response! In my mind, I would still think of Monday as being weekday #1, but I think you've clarified that it is a 'decision decision' more than anything else when the datetime module was created. Fun fact: In Chinese 'Monday' is 周一, which literally means weekday one. 